# Euler-Equations in gradient form

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I was looking at the following form of the Euler equations:

$$\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t}+(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{v}+\frac{1}{\rho} \operatorname{grad}(p)=\vec{k} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \frac{\partial v_{i}}{\partial t}+\sum_{j=1}^{3} \frac{\partial v_{i}}{\partial x_{j}} v_{j}+\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_{i}}=k_{i}, \quad i=1,2,3$$

But I don't understand the notation of the gradient ($(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{v}$)
 Because I only know the gradient for scalar valued functions from $\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

It looks to me as if the gradient of a vector field is defined as the Jacobian. Is this correct?

Comment: Interesting that you chose not to use the Del operator for the *actual* grad function, but then referred to the Del operator as grad when it wasn't denoting grad.

Comment: The formula is taken directly from wikipedia...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v}$ is called convective derivative of the flow velocity and is called convective acceleration.

Using Einstein notation : $\vec{v} = v_i \hat{e}_i$, where $v_i$ represents the velocity component along $\hat{e}_i$ direction; $i = 1,2,3$. (Note: $i$ is a dummy index and we can represent it by any other letter as well).

Similarly, $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \hat{e}_i$;  $i = 1,2,3$

Let us study the expression term by term:

- $\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} \hat{e}_i$
- $(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v} = (v_j \hat{e}_j \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\hat{e}_j) v_i \hat{e}_i =  \sum_{j=1}^3 v_j \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} \hat{e}_i$
- $\frac{1}{\rho} \text{grad}(p) = \frac{1}{\rho} \nabla p = \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}\hat{e}_i$
- $\vec{k} = k_i \hat{e}_i$

Now, let us gather all terms along $\hat{e}_i$ direction, we get
$$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} + \sum_{j=1}^3 v_j \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} = k_i,\hspace{3mm} i = 1,2,3$$

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

This is operator notation, and the triangle operator in question is **Del** (or Nabla). It isn't the **Grad** operator, which is the **Del** operator (by its lonesome) appearing in front of a *scalar* function.

The dot product of a vector and **Del** is a scalar like any other dot product. So you have a scalar multiplied by a vector.

By itself, I don't know of any name for *just that operator part*, but it is the normal notation for these terms in the [Material Derivative](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473758/convective-derivative-vs-total-derivative).

The [Jacobian](https://medium.com/@ravikalia/nabla-the-thread-linking-grad-jacobian-and-hessian-operators-8747bd0b6e17) (or its transpose, I couldn't figure out which) has the similar nine terms, but is a dyadic 3 X 3 form. This is a 3 x 1 vector with each member having three terms.

Comment: The Jacobian *is* an extension of the gradient, but this isn't that.

Comment: Thanks. But then I don't understand how the two formulas I've written above are equivalent. Could you help me out?

Comment: Unpack the expression in parentheses and evaluate it.